# Unable to print or Log non english strings e.g arabic,chinese characters using Groovy in SOAP UI

Tags: file-io, groovy, utf-8, soapui, assertions

Following is my code and i want to assert this text from responses .I am reading file content which consist of Arabic and chinese strings

Format of Text file is

```
10911= الأصول مع تعريب
10912= الأصمع تعريب
```

Groovy code as follows

```
Properties properties = new Properties()
def file = new File(''C\properties.txt'))
InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(file.getBytes());
properties.load(is)
log.info  properties."10911".toString()
```

Getting Response as

Ø§Ù?Ø£ØµÙ?Ù? Ù?Ø¹ ØªØ¹Ø±Ù?Ø¨

How to log it in arabic or chiinese  in soapui

Comment: What is the encoding? See Menu -> Help -> System properties.

Comment: @Rao  :This file content encoding using groovy in SOAP UI , its nothing to do with system properties , I have some arabic and chinese words which i want to assert from file values

Comment: is the text in arabic the key or the number on the left?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to `file/Preferences` in soapUI

in `HTTP Settings` `Response compression` must be unchecked.

Answer (score 0):

Load `Properties` from UTF-enabled `Reader`:

```
Properties properties = new Properties()
def file = new File('C:\\properties.txt'))
file.withReader('UTF-8') { properties.load(it) }
log.info(properties."10911".toString())
```